# Design operator++ for iterating over certain elements of a multimap

Tags: c++, iterator, nested-class

I have the following class declaration:

```
class Dictionnary{
  private:
    map< int,list<string> > data;
  public:
    bool isPrime();
    class prime_iterator{
      private:
        map< int,list<string> >::iterator it;
      public:
        iterator(){}
        prime_iterator & operator++(){
          ++it;
            while(it != data.end() && !isPrime(it->first)){
            ++it;
          }
          return it;
        }
        ...
};
```

which is intended to provide an iterator over prime keys of a  `map<int,list<string>>`. I'm not sure operator++ is well implemented.

First, is it a good design to do `it != data.end()`accessing the outer class? Second, is operator++ returning the right thing or should return only prime_iterator?. Also, can you think about any better solution?

Comment: How do you access `data` from the inner class? I think you could pass a reference or something of it at your `prime_iterator` constructor. 

Also, you need to create your `map<int, list<string>>::iterator it` from `prime_iterator` somewhere. Maybe you could do it by (as I already said) passing a reference to the constructor and creating this iterator there too. You can also just keep `begin()` (to traverse) and `end()` (to check the end) at your `prime_iterator`. 

With that, I see it ok to use it that way, you're just wrapping another iterator for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to always try to find solution elsewhere - if not found - then only create by yourself:

You can use [`boost::fiter_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)

For your case it would look in this way:

```
#include <boost/iterator/filter_iterator.hpp>

using DataMap = std::map<int, std::list<std::string>>;
struct is_prime_number {
  bool operator()(const DataMap::value_type& x) { return x.first % 2 == 0; }
}; // I know this is just is_even - not is_prime :D

using DataMapPrimeIter = boost::filter_iterator<is_prime_number, DataMap::iterator>;
inline DataMapPrimeIter only_prime_begin(DataMap& dataMap)
{
    return boost::make_filter_iterator<is_prime_number>(dataMap.begin(), dataMap.end());
}
inline DataMapPrimeIter only_prime_end(DataMap& dataMap)
{
    return boost::make_filter_iterator<is_prime_number>(dataMap.end(), dataMap.end());
}
```

And usage:

```
int main()
{
    DataMap dataMap{{1,{"A","B"}}, {2,{"C", "D", "E"}}};
    for (auto i = only_prime_begin(dataMap), end = only_prime_end(dataMap); i != end; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i->first << i->second.front() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you want to have your own implementation, or you cannot use boost in your project - then look at boost implementation - it is for free to look at...

Answer (score 1):

My humble solution. The `typedef` is just for convenience.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::map<int, std::string> map_t;

class Dictionary {
private:
    map_t& m_map;
public:
    class prime_iterator {
    public:
        prime_iterator( map_t::iterator begin, map_t::iterator end )
            : m_current(begin), m_end(end) {
            runUntilPrime();
        }

        prime_iterator& operator++() {
            m_current++;
            runUntilPrime();
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator != (prime_iterator other) {
            return other.m_current != m_current;
        }

        map_t::value_type& operator* () {
            return *m_current;
        }

    private:
        map_t::iterator m_current;
        map_t::iterator m_end;

        bool isPrime(int x) {
            std::vector<int> primes = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };
            return std::find( primes.begin(), primes.end(), x ) != primes.end();
        }

        void runUntilPrime() {
            while( m_current != m_end && !isPrime(m_current->first) ) {
                m_current++;
            }
        }

    };

    Dictionary( map_t& tmap )
        : m_map(tmap) {}

    prime_iterator begin() {
        return prime_iterator( m_map.begin(), m_map.end() );
    }

    prime_iterator end () {
        return prime_iterator(m_map.end(), m_map.end());
    }

};

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

    map_t map;

    map.emplace(0, "zero");
    map.emplace(1, "one");
    map.emplace(2, "two");
    map.emplace(3, "three");
    map.emplace(4, "four");
    map.emplace(5, "five");
    map.emplace(6, "six");
    map.emplace(7, "seven");
    map.emplace(8, "eight");
    map.emplace(9, "nine");
    map.emplace(10, "ten");
    map.emplace(13, "thirteen");

    Dictionary dict( map );

    for( auto p : dict ) {
        std::cout << p.first << "\t" << p.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```